# blackberry 10 android launcher widget

Tags: android, android-widget, blackberry-10

I see all the ads about porting "my android app to blackberry 10" and I have ported an android app to blackberry playbook in simulator before

but does blackberry 10 support android launcher (aka home screen) widgets? thanks

if so what is the process or the programming differences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Home screen widgets are not supported. The BlackBerry Runtime for Android Apps only supports Android 2.3.3 applications without widgets.

From the [documentation](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_app_types.html):

> The following types of applications are not supported. Applications
>   of these types will not be permitted for sale or distribution:
>
> ```
> - Widget apps
> [...]
> ```

Comment: @Ahmad thanks for the link, it mentions apps that have widgets as secondary functionality work, you should know that Android after 3.0 actually doesn't officially support apps that are only widgets or apps that have no launchable activity either. (the widgets are still accessible after the launcher is reset, by rebooting or changing the locale) This isn't a dealbreaker, as long as the widgets actually work on the screen with blackberry, which is what I want to confirm

Comment: As mentioned before, BB10 does not support any homescreen widgets.